# How can I enable auto complete support in Notepad++?

Tags: autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

I am trying to add simple syntax highlighting and auto completion for a simple scripting language...

I added syntax highlighting using [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/25/creating-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad.aspx)

Now I want to know how to enable auto completion with Notepad ++ for my custom language. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For basic autocompletion, have a look at the files in `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\plugins\APIs`.  It's basically just an XML file with keywords in.  If you want calltips ("function parameters hint"), check out [these instructions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/auto-completion/).

I've never found any more documentation, but `cpp.xml` has a calltip for `fopen`, while `php.xml` is quite complete.

Comment: Auto complete documentation is now here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Auto_Completion

Comment: Is there any way for Notepad++ to autocomplete xml when using an xml schema?

Comment: Documentation moved yet again: http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Auto_Completion - Also, instructions on creating auto-completion files: http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files

Comment: @AgentRev The links are dead again.

Comment: @DebugErr: lol, new links: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion - http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files

Comment: Thanks :) I browsed them up with archive.org already and created my own auto-completion. Too bad it doesn't support contexts like classes :(

Comment: The link has changed again, now the docs are here: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/auto-completion/

Answer (score 120):

The link provided by Mark no longer works, but you can go to:

**Notpad++ 6.6.9**

- Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion -> Enable auto-completion on each input.

I find it very annoying though, since a big autocomplete block is always coming up and I would just like to see autocomplete when I press tab or a key combination. I am fairly new to Notepad++ though. If you know of such a key combination, please feel free to reply. I found this question via Google, so we can always help others.[image]

Comment: Turn it off and use `Ctrl+Enter` for your code, and `Ctrl+Space` for language, instead. The setting seems to be precisely for auto-showing that box|block.

Comment: naxa's technique is what I was looking for, not the complex other answers. perfect!  can't believe I haven't been using this :)

Comment: Naxa - can you make your comment into an answer? I'd upvote it!

Answer (score 21):

Go to

> Settings -> Preferences -> Backup/Autocompletion

- Check **Enable auto-completion on each input**. By default the radio button for **Function completion** gets checked, that will complete related function name as you type. But when you are editing something other than code, you can check for **Word completion**.
- Check **Function parameters hint on input**, if you find it difficult to remember function parameters and their ordering.

Answer (score 8):

Autocomplete in Notepad++ is as simple as hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> in the interface.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> - as simple as that!

This, for many people, will be better than autocompleting on everything.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add your libraries & check your versions. Good information is in *[Using Notepad Plus Plus as a script editor](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Using_Notepad_Plus_Plus_as_a_script_editor)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add your own suggestion.

Open this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\APIs
```

And open the XML file of the language, such as php.xml. Here suppose, you would like to add **addcslashes**, so just add this XML code.

```
<KeyWord name="addcslashes" func="yes">
    <Overload retVal="void">
        <Param name="void"/>
    </Overload>
</KeyWord>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy:

1. Find the XML file with unity keywords
2. Copy only lines with "< KeyWord name="......" / > "
3. Go to C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\APIs and find cs.xml for example
4. Paste what you copied in 1., but be careful: Don't delete any line of it cs.xml
5. Save the file and enjoy autocompleting :)

Answer (score 0):

Open Notepad++ and Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion -> Check the Auto-insert options you want. 
this link will help alot: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion