# Is Intellisense possible with the appMobi XDK?

Tags: intellisense, code-completion, appmobi

Is there a way to set up code-completion/intellisense against the appMobi XDK API, using either Visual Studio 2010 or Notepad++?

Is Intellisense possible with the appMobi XDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it is possible, but as far as I know appMobi XDK commands haven't been built into an autocomplete package.  Here's a link describing how it might be done: [How Can I Enable Auto Complete Support in Notepad Plus Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893761/how-can-i-enable-auto-complete-support-in-notepad)

It sounds like that is something appMobi should make.  Of the two editors you mentioned, Notepad++ or Visual Studio, which would you rather have an intellisense plug in for the appMobi XDK for first?

Comment: Visual Studio would be my personal preference.

Comment: Unfortunately, we started with Notepad++ this morning.  I'll try to get back around to Visual Studio here soon.  Here's the link: http://appmobi.com/documentation/index.php?DOC=NOTEPAD_PLUSPLUS_INTELLISENSE