# notepad++ how to convert to typing assistant like?

Tags: text, autocomplete, notepad++

*I was using notepad++ to create a report and its taking a quite a  while for me to type and do so.
Well i had tried a software called typing assistant it was really good(except for the money part :D).*

> **TO the Point :
>                  is there any way tat i can link a dict(text file of words) and use notepad ++  as typing assistant please tell me if so i
>   can speed my report.**

*Cause i am a programmer too so i really like the keyword completion and stuff .But is there a way to use it for text ?*

already tried Phrase Express -.-:
                                   Takes long and its kinda for macro text and text completion don't work tat fast for me to tab and complete

if there's a question in the form like mine link me to tat :
                                                         i searched it and i didn't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up your own custom auto-complete dictionaries in notepad++.  You need to create an xml file with your language name and put it under the plugins/APIs directory in notepad++.  Of course this assumes you know how to write xml.  There's a formal description of how to implement this [here](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Editing_Configuration_Files#Autocompletion.2C_aka_API.2C_files).

I've never tried to create an auto-complete dictionary for plain text files, so I'm not sure if it's possible, but I have successfully created them for user-defined languages, which you could also do if you can't get it to work with text files.

I'm not sure if this question is really a duplicate, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893761/how-can-i-enable-auto-complete-support-in-notepad?rq=1) is a very similar one, which may help you in your research.