# Notepad++ Auto-Complete

Tags: autocomplete, lua, notepad++

I am looking to see if anyone can guide me to constructing an Auto-Complete XML plugin for Lua.  I know all about the LOVE thing, but I have no idea how to set it up so it supports metatables too.

For example

```
local npc = Npc(getNpcCid()) -- This creates an instance of Npc metatable
npc:getName()
```

Does anyone know how I can make it so it shows a list of all methods in the Npc() metatable when I type "npc:"?

Check out this YouTube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muJvM-Hz6w4

The person that made that video is showing that something like this is possible, but I don't know how to make that possible in the XML plugin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable auto complete support in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893761/how-can-i-enable-auto-complete-support-in-notepad)

Comment: @hjpotter92 The scenarios are not even similar.

Answer (score 0):

afaik np++ is not able to search and parse the class outline of separated files. So custom class methods are not able to be detected.
It's auto-complete setting is only for pre-defined static functions only.