# Is there any way to make NotePad ++ autocompletion for PHP as powerful as NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, web, autocomplete, notepad++

I know my question would look silly to some people, but its not.

NetBeans provide more than just auto-completion, because NetBeans is a complete IDE. But I always use NetBeans only because I need its completion feature, nothing more.
But NetBeans is heavy compare to NotePad++.
Notepad++ already have auto-complete option for PHP, but its not as powerful as NetBeans's auto-completion, because if you try something like try-catch, it won't provide the completion.

If anyone know how to make NotePad++ auto-completion as strong as Netbeans autocompletion, please let me know (I googled it a lot, but didn't find the proper resource).

(Sorry for any grammatical mistakes, I am not a native speaker)

Comment: It doesn't look silly, I just wonder if it is off-topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable auto complete support in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893761/how-can-i-enable-auto-complete-support-in-notepad)